# Warning package.json: No license field $ TARGET_ENV='dev' gatsby develop

Tags: typescript, environment-variables, gatsby

Iam trying learn Typescript and iam using public repo to start with it.
github repo: https://github.com/tahowallet/taho.xyz

when I run `yarn start` I got this warning

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.22
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ TARGET_ENV='dev' gatsby develop
'TARGET_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The `package.json` contains the following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "TARGET_ENV='dev' gatsby develop",
    "start": "TARGET_ENV='dev' gatsby develop",
    "start:stg": "TARGET_ENV='stg' gatsby develop",
    "start:prd": "TARGET_ENV='prd' gatsby develop",
    "build": "TARGET_ENV='dev' gatsby build",
    "build:stg": "TARGET_ENV='stg' gatsby build",
    "build:prd": "TARGET_ENV='prd' gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\""
  }
```

The directory is organised in the following way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYa9T.png)

try learn to run this code